# I can't get my data mode in excel or google sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I want to check a field for statistical analysis by means of mode, average, etc. I got all the average, maximum, minimum, and average states through Excel formulas, but when I want to get the mode of this field, I get this error I get "error not available error".

[image]

I checked the entire field but there is no non-numeric or empty value in the field.
I used the following formula:

```
=MODE(Table1[[#All]؛[Applicant_ID]])
```

I tried this in both Excel and Google Sheets, but there is no answer in both.

Comment: `If the data set contains no duplicate data points, MODE returns the #N/A error value.` from:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mode-function-e45192ce-9122-4980-82ed-4bdc34973120#:~:text=If%20the%20data%20set%20contains%20no%20duplicate%20data%20points%2C%20MODE%20returns%20the%20%23N/A%20error%20value.

Comment: It looks as though there is no mode, i.e. the Applicant_ID's are all different.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to perform average, max, min, mode on a set of IDs. What is the average of an ID supposed to represent?

Comment: I am also aware of this, but this is for an academic project and the question asks that if you have numerical data, do this statistical analysis on it.
@BigBen

Comment: An ID is categorical data, I'd argue, even if it takes the form of a number. Average, max, min, mode are not actually meaningful here.

Comment: If its academic project, i think the best person to speak with is your faculty advisor, because they are being paid for that so that you can overcome your issues in Excel or Google Sheets.